# Using Vuforia provided Projection Matrix and Marker Pose in SceneKit

Tags: scenekit, vuforia

Currently I'm trying to troubleshoot the use of the projection matrix and framemarker pose when rendering in SceneKit. The model in the scene and the camera image background appear without problems. However, once I change the projection matrix and framemarker pose matrix to match Vuforia everything is pushed offscreen.

```
func didUpdateProjectionMatrix(projectionMatrix: matrix_float4x4)
{
    let extrinsic = SCNMatrix4FromMat4(projectionMatrix)
    let camera = self.cameraNode?.camera
    camera?.setProjectionTransform(extrinsic)
}

func didUpdateFramemarkers(framemarkers: [Framemarker]?)
{
    guard let framemarkers = framemarkers else {
        return
    }

    for framemarker in framemarkers {
        let pose = SCNMatrix4Invert(SCNMatrix4FromMat4(framemarker.pose))
        self.objectNode?.transform = pose
    }
}
```

Is this a correct way to setup the SCNCamera and object node and is there anything else required to setup Vuforia framemarkers to work with SceneKit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### It just works!

The hard part is determining what pieces of SceneKit are necessary to make this work. Originally I read the article [Making Augmented Reality app easily with Scenekit + Vuforia](http://qiita.com/akira108/items/a743138fca532ee193fe) which outlined how to rejigger the sample app for user-defined targets. The downsides to that article include that it isn't always clear what the author changed, no sample project is provided, and it is based upon an older version of Vuforia. Ultimately, I found it unnecessary to invert the pose matrix.

#### Draw camera image and set projection matrix and update marker pose

```
override func viewDidLoad() 
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let scene = SmartScanScene()

    let camera = SCNCamera()
    let cameraNode = SCNNode()
    cameraNode.camera = camera
    scene.rootNode.addChildNode(cameraNode)
    _cameraNode = cameraNode

    let view = self.view as! SCNView
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    view.showsStatistics = true
    // view.debugOptions = SCNDebugOptions.ShowBoundingBoxes.union(.ShowWireframe)
    view.autoenablesDefaultLighting = true
    view.allowsCameraControl = false
}

func didUpdateProjectionMatrix(projectionMatrix: matrix_float4x4)
{
    let extrinsic = SCNMatrix4FromMat4(projectionMatrix)
    _cameraNode?.camera?.setProjectionTransform(extrinsic)
}

func didUpdateFramemarkers(framemarkers: [Framemarker]?)
{
    guard let framemarkers = framemarkers else {
        return
    }

    for framemarker in framemarkers {
        let pose = SCNMatrix4FromMat4(framemarker.pose)
        self.objectNode?.transform = pose
    }
}

func didUpdateCameraImage(image: UIImage?)
{
    if let image = image {
        _scene?.background.contents = image
    }
}
```

Comment: Cameron, can you please share how you set up Vuforia to work with the code in your answer? Did you create an ObjC wrapper for Vuforia? How do you get the camera video as background in your scene? Thanks

Comment: @Manuel http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41952037/bypass-vuforias-handling-of-the-camera-image-and-pose/41952038#41952038

Comment: Hi Cameron. I am trying to do something similar but using opencv directly and scene kit. They use different coordinate system and that it screwing me over for a week now. :) Just to make sure that I am understanding things right. Shouldn't the extrinsic variable in didUpdateProj be called intrinsic and we form the projection matrix from the intrinsic params ? And the frame marker pose, why aren't you inverting it ? Isn't the pose , the transform of the camera with respect to the model, so to get the model in camera, shouldn't you transpose it. Any help is appreciated :).

Comment: Sounding like me. I too did this in OpenCV at one point. Terminology changes depending on the person you're talking to, but you can think of extrinsic as originating from outside, intrinsic in the sense it is fundamental to the camera. Intrinsic is more correct in this context. The math depends on the matrices and what happens for you and what is automatic. The biggest issue is probably converting between OpenCV and SceneKit matrices and even subtle errors do not yield obvious visual clues.

Comment: While technically a matrix inversion is required in a mathematical sense, the transform property handles this correctly. SceneKit is meant to take a lot of the minutiae of working in a 3D scene graph away from the developer and in every case you need to test from fundamentals to get an idea of what is going on internally.