# Bypass Vuforia's handling of the camera image and pose

Tags: vuforia

I want to bypass Vuforia's display handling of the camera image and pose of framemarkers on iOS, is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `- (void)QCAR_onUpdate:(QCAR::State *)state` you can grab the camera data and the marker poses.

#### Camera image data

```
QCAR::Frame frame = state->getFrame();

for (int i = 0; i < frame.getNumImages(); i++) {
    const QCAR::Image *image = frame.getImage(i);
    if (image->getFormat() == kQCARFrameFormat) {

        const void *pixelData = image->getPixels();
        int width = image->getWidth();
        int height = image->getHeight();

    }
}
```

#### Marker poses

```
NSMutableArray *mutableFramemarkers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:state->getNumTrackableResults()];
for (int i = 0; i < state->getNumTrackableResults(); i++) {
    const QCAR::TrackableResult *trackableResult = state->getTrackableResult(i);
    const QCAR::MarkerResult *markerResult = static_cast<const    QCAR::MarkerResult *>(trackableResult);
    const QCAR::Marker &marker = markerResult->getTrackable();
    QCAR::Matrix44F qcarPose = QCAR::Tool::convertPose2GLMatrix(trackableResult->getPose());
}
```

Comment: I tried that, can you please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42035046/how-to-calculate-the-camera-position-from-vuforia-gl-matrix