# How to calculate the camera position from Vuforia GL matrix?

Tags: swift, camera, augmented-reality, scenekit, vuforia

I calculate the camera position of a `SCNScene` that is rendered in Vuforia. However the object is not staying fixed on the marker but jumping around when moving. The cube in the scene appears only orthographically, no matter how the device is moved around the sides cannot be seen.

The camera position is calculated with every frame:

```
// Get model view matrix
Vuforia::Matrix44F modelViewMatrix = Vuforia::Tool::convertPose2GLMatrix(result->getPose());

// Convert to extrinsic matrix
SCNMatrix4 extrinsic = [self SCNMatrix4FromVuforiaMatrix44: modelViewMatrix];
SCNMatrix4 inverted = SCNMatrix4Invert(extrinsic);

// Set new position of SCNCamera
cameraNode.transform = inverted;
```

The camera projection matrix is calculated when the camera is stared:

```
// Get device camera calibration    
const Vuforia::CameraCalibration& cameraCalibration = Vuforia::CameraDevice::getInstance().getCameraCalibration();
projectionGLMatrix = Vuforia::Tool::getProjectionGL(cameraCalibration, 2.0f, 5000.0f);

// Convert matrix
GLKMatrix4 glkMatrix;

for(int i=0; i<16; i++) {
    glkMatrix.m[i] = projectionGLMatrix.data[i];
}

// Convert matrix
SCNMatrix4 projectionTransform = SCNMatrix4FromGLKMatrix4(glkMatrix);
cameraNode.camera.projectionTransform = projectionTransform;
```

What am I doing wrong here?

## Update 1

The projection matrix is now calculated like this, when the camera starts:

```
const Vuforia::CameraCalibration& cameraCalibration = Vuforia::CameraDevice::getInstance().getCameraCalibration();
Vuforia::Matrix44F vuforiaMatrix = Vuforia::Tool::getProjectionGL(cameraCalibration, 2.0f, 5000.0f);
matrix_float4x4 simdMatrix = simdMatrixWithVuforiaMatrix44F(vuforiaMatrix);
cameraNode.camera.projectionTransform = SCNMatrix4FromMat4(simdMatrix);
```

The camera position is updated with every frame:

```
Vuforia::Matrix44F modelViewMatrix = Vuforia::Tool::convertPose2GLMatrix(result->getPose());
matrix_float4x4 simdMatrix = simdMatrixWithVuforiaMatrix44F(modelViewMatrix);
cameraNode.transform = SCNMatrix4FromMat4(simdMatrix);

NSLog(@"camera position: x%lf, y%lf, z%lf, rotation: x%lf, y%lf, z%lf", _cameraNode.position.x, _cameraNode.position.y, _cameraNode.position.z, _cameraNode.rotation.x, _cameraNode.rotation.y, _cameraNode.rotation.z);
```

By moving the device and observing the logging of the camera position (left graph) and rotation (right graph) it seems that the axes are:
[image]

The axes for rotation are different from position axes. Also a rotation around the remaining axis (untitled in the graph below) does not have any influence on the cameraNode.rotation.x value which floats around 0.999.

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

You're experiencing classic - "I did something wrong with the matrix" behaviour that takes lots of trial-and-error to resolve. I also think you've been reading stuff on Vuforia's website which is almost never helpful. :)

Re-arranging the matrices is probably where you're going wrong. The `SCNMatrix` is supposed to be directly compatible with OpenGL. I actually put everything into the `simd::matrix4x4` and use the built in `SCNMatrix4FromMat4` to convert them to `SCNMatrix`.

> SceneKit uses matrices to represent coordinate space transformations,
>   which in turn can represent the combined position, rotation or
>   orientation, and scale of an object in three-dimensional space.
>   SceneKit matrix structures are in row-major order, so they are
>   suitable for passing to shader programs or OpenGL APIs that accept
>   matrix parameters.

So, to sum up... I believe you should delete:

```
SCNMatrix4 inverted = SCNMatrix4Invert(extrinsic);
```

As for the copying of the `GLMatrix` to an `SCNMatrix`, without trying it, should be correct. Compare the result of the projection matrix generated using your method to mine. They should be identical.

### Projection matrix

I'm getting the projection matrix like this:

```
const Vuforia::Matrix44F projectionMatrix = Vuforia::Tool::getProjectionGL(cameraCalibration, nearPlane, farPlane);
simdMatrixWithVuforiaMatrix44F(projectionMatrix);
```

I convert the matrix to a `simd::matrix4x4` (I spend a lot of time in C++-land) which is just an Apple defined struct for which SceneKit has support.

```
#include <simd/simd.h>

matrix_float4x4 simdMatrixWithVuforiaMatrix44F(const Vuforia::Matrix44F &matrix)
{
    vector_float4 col0 = { matrix.data[0], matrix.data[1], matrix.data[2], matrix.data[3] };
    vector_float4 col1 = { matrix.data[4], matrix.data[5], matrix.data[6], matrix.data[7] };
    vector_float4 col2 = { matrix.data[8], matrix.data[9], matrix.data[10], matrix.data[11] };
    vector_float4 col3 = { matrix.data[12], matrix.data[13], matrix.data[14], matrix.data[15] };

    return matrix_from_columns(col0, col1, col2, col3);
}
```

Back in the view controller

```
let extrinsic = SCNMatrix4FromMat4(projectionMatrix)
_cameraNode?.camera?.projectionTransform = extrinsic
```

#### Framemarker poses

I have an object called a Framemarker that actually contains both the identifier and pose, but that pose is just the same `simd::matrix4x4` as the projection matrix.

```
for framemarker in framemarkers {
        switch framemarker.identifier {
        case 337:
            let pose = SCNMatrix4FromMat4(framemarker.pose)
            _firstNode?.transform = pose
            break
        case 357:
            let pose = SCNMatrix4FromMat4(framemarker.pose)
            _secondNode?.transform = pose
            break
        default:
            break
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the x, y, z position of the camera is the same with your method. However I have the same problem, that the object does not stay on the parker when i move the device. Moving the device to the right (+x) does not move the rendered object to the left on the screen. Here is a video that explains it better: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/71604584/vuforia_1.m4v

Comment: I just realized I am only updating the projection matrix of the camera in `renderFrameVuforia` but not transforming any other node of the scene. Is that the reason maybe? Btw. I am using a SCNRenderer.

Comment: The projection matrix is updated one time on start, after that you need to update the pose of the node representing your object on every refresh/callback.

Comment: My bad, the projection matrix is only calculated once. The camera node is then updated every frame. All other nodes stay the same. I think there is something wrong with the matrix conversion, please see the code update #1 in my post.

Comment: @Manuel why would you update the camera every frame?! It gets the projection matrix and therefore it only gets updated once. The pose is handed to the other nodes/objects in the scene.

Comment: I wanted to use a SCNScene, place the object and a camera in there and then let vuforia move the camera node. Is that a wrong approach? Do I have to place the camera fixed and move the object node around?

Comment: AR with the camera is all about marrying the 'physical camera' to the 'virtual camera'. The 3D graphical camera should see the world the same way as the physical camera and everything in the scene will be positioned within that context. So just for testing, try setting the camera with the projection matrix and then passing the poses to the objects.

Comment: @Manuel In case it wasn't clear, I'm using an SCNScene.

Comment: Hi Cameron, the last couple of days I was reading more into the calculations behind coordinate systems. I understand it better now but still I still wasn't able to fix this. I think it has something to do that there are matrices used with different axis rotations. Will keep you posted.